# como paso un parametro id a una ruta get c#

Tags: c#, angular

Hola estoy intentando pasar un parámetro **id** desde una ruta angular a **c#**, solo que me marca un 404, estoy creando un ruta que tiene queryParams donde lleva un id y un lang

```
myruta.com/unacategoria/44?id=44&lang=es
```

el primer 44 es el que intento pasar como parametro, aunque se que pasa en el queryParam lo ocupo en ese punto de la url,

**Peticion get angular a c#**

```
 let myParams = { id: 44, lang: "es" };
 this.http.get(this.createUrl(`{id}`), myParams);
```

**c#**

```
 [HttpGet("{id}")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetCategory(int id, string lang = "es")
```

Y en respuesta me aparece un 404

si hago algo como `myruta.com/44/test?id=44&lang=es`  **funciona sin problema** porque agregue un texto después del 44, mmm pero solo quiero dejar el numero por mera convención

Comment: pues elimina el parametro string lang = "es" y  envia solo myruta.com/nombeController?id=44 y  declara  [HttpGet]

Comment: La ruta que tienes `[HttpGet("{id}")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetCategory(int id, string lang = "es")` deberia funcionar con `http://localhost:1234/Controller/44` si lo pruebas desde `postman`, ahora supongo que tienes que la ruta del controller sea el mismo nombre del controller, entonces primero revisa que la ruta funcione como esperas desde postman despues checa bien en angular que valor exacto le estas mandando a la ruta, o puedes simplemente poner `http://localhost:1234/Controller/44` suponiendo que tus rutas son algo asi, si tu app usa swagger checa que ruta te da alli